# Which Python version to be used for building PyPi package?

Tags: python, build, pypi

I'm building PyPi package, which is compatible with Python 3.8 and higher.
That means that the minimum version of Python is 3.8, so I build the package in Python 3.8 environment.

My question is should I build package separately for Python 3.8 and 3.9?
I think the thing that actually builds package is the module, `build`, so the version of Python doesn't matter. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version does not matter, you can technically build a package using Python `3.9` which can also work on Python `3.8`. The quickest and easiest way to ensure version compatibility would be to build it on the minimum version that you intend to support, so I would suggest building once using `3.8`.

If you want to test that the package will work on different Python versions, you can use [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run your automated tests on multiple versions in an easy way (automated tests are tests that you execute through [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/) or [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)).

[Here is how Python does its versioning](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/?highlight=version#development-cycle) and what the versions signify. Assuming that you are building the package to have it work on version `3.8` and all subsequent `3.x` versions, then if it builds and works for `3.8`, it will **almost** certainly work for `3.9`, `3.10`, `3.11` etc...

Although major versions such as `2.x` and `3.x` (and `4.x` if it ever gets released) will have enough incompatible changes between them that it is not safe to assume that they are compatible.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful :)

Comment: This is only true for pure Python wheels. If the wheel has a C extension the version absolutely does matter.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you gonna publish. If you build and publish an sdist (source distribution, .tar.gz) — Python version doesn't matter. If you build and publish a source wheel — Python version doesn't matter. If you build and publish a binary wheel with compiled extension(s) written in C — Python version matters very much and you must build wheels for every major Python version separately.

Answer (score 0):

Python will load a wheel based on API, ABI, OS, Architecture tags that it supports. For pure Python wheels you largely get fairly universal compatibility.

For wheels with C extensions however, the ABI version must match the interpreter. CPython 3.10 will not load a wheel built for Python 3.9.

The only C extensions that are forward-compatible are ones built with the [Stable API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html). These extensions declare what Python version they're built against and can only use a limited subset of the API. In exchange they declare an `abi3` ABI and can be loaded by newer Python versions. Note that `pybind11` does NOT support the stable API.

To see the full list of tag combinations for your Python run:

```
$ python -m pip debug --verbose
...
Compatible tags: 450
...
  cp310-cp310-macosx_10_7_universal2
  cp310-cp310-macosx_10_6_universal2
...
  cp310-abi3-macosx_10_7_universal2
  cp310-abi3-macosx_10_6_universal2
...
  cp310-none-macosx_10_5_universal2
  cp310-none-macosx_10_4_universal2
  cp39-abi3-macosx_13_0_arm64
  cp39-abi3-macosx_13_0_universal2
...
```

So my Python 3.10 will load wheels built for Python 3.10, stable API wheels built all the way back to 3.2, and pure-python wheels. That's it.

The practical way to deal with this is to use a tool like `cibuildwheel` in your CI pipeline (like GitHub Actions) to [build all the combinations](https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#build-skip).